# Closure of "How Old is the pythagorean theorem?"

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

Can someone supply more clarity on why [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/how-old-is-the-pythagorean-theorem) has been re-closed?